# How do I exclude zero as a minimum value when trying to find the min value of a row using xlrd

Tags: python-3.7, min, xlrd

I have an existing excel spreadsheet where I want to find the minimum value of each row. I am able to do this, however, I want to ignore any zero's as a minimum value.

So if row 1 had the values [12 6 8 0 19 4], I would like the program to state that the minimum value is 4.

I used the following code to determine the minimum value in a row using xlrd, but it doesn't ignore zeros.

```
Minimum = min(sheet1.row_values(1, start_colx=1, end_colx=6))
print(Minimum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use list comprehension to exclude the 0's of the list:

`[value for value in list if value!=0]`

And use the minimum function over the result:

```py
list=sheet1.row_values(1, start_colx=1, end_colx=6)
Minimum = min([value for value in list if value!=0])
print(Minimum)
```